# Express configured to use CORS does not accept CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, cors

I've got some weird stuff going on with Express.  I have an endpoint that takes logging data and shoves it into a postgres db, but I'm getting this error on requests:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver.com/log' from origin 'https://myorigin.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This doesn't make any sense because I've configured the express app to accept CORS and it looks like options requests are accepted?  Here's the relevant server side code

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());
```

and here's the request

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://myserver.com/log",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "username": "test", "json": {a: 1}}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

I have tried

```js
app.use(cors())
```

and

```js
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
```

to no avail.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `cors` npm module and import into your server.js or index.js file. Ideally you should install by `npm install -save cors`

And then use as below

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');  // from cors npm module
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Yes, I tried using that method as well and it produced the same error.